# Playing an emission particle on collision not working?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want a particle system to play when a collision happens, the particle system is an explosion, but it keeps saying

"Cannot modify the return value of ParticleSystem.emission because it's not a variable"

Here is the code.

```
public Particle explosion;
void Start()
{
    explosion.emission.enabled = false;



    }


private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
   if(collision.gameObject.name == "Cube")
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        explosion.Play();

        UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene("GameOver");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling and enabling the Explosion you can Instantiate the game object(Explosions) whenever collision occurs.

```
public Transform Explosion;
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
   if(collision.gameObject.name == "Cube")
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        Instantiate(explosion);

        UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene("GameOver");

    }
}
```

However after fireworks you are changing scenes so it might not show the fireworks, as the firework gameobject gets destroyed when scene changes. You can use a coroutine for that.